# Finally Clause in SQL Server Transaction? Something that will execute irrespective of success or failure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, transactions, try-catch-finally, sqltransaction

In SQL Server, is there something similar to `finally` clause in `try..catch...` block of c# ?

I mean, I am using `BEGIN TRAN, END TRAN, COMMIT TRAN, ROLLBACK TRAN` etc in a SQL Server transaction and want a section or some set of actions that needs to fire irrespective of success or failure or transaction.

Is there a solution for that? (similar to finally block on try/catch of OOPS languages).

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175976.aspx There isn't anything as of this time. As long as the query doesn't bomb out, you should be able to just add code after the `END CATCH` to do what you need.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL Server TRY CATCH FINALLY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25789859/sql-server-try-catch-finally)

Answer (score 3):

There isn't *anything* that will run "irrespective of success or failure" with 100% reliability. It doesn't matter whether you're talking about the "finally" clause of a C# program, or a BEGIN TRY...END TRY BEGIN CATCH...END CATCH stucture on SQL Server.

The problem is that terminal blocks like these can't execute under *every possible* failure mode. Every *possible* failure mode has to include software, hardware, and network failures. If your client is the government, it probably has to include missle attacks, too.

Obligatory reference to a [classic TheDailyWTF](http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/My-Tales.aspx).

Comment: + 1 for providing the link to `classic TheDailyWTF`, which demonstrates misunderstanding about the `finally` block.

Comment: I am quite sure the question wasn't about hardware-wise problems. The asker just wants to know if it is possible to make the same behavior of finally blocks in c# in T-SQL. Also, if the server is attacked by missiles, government will have some more serious things to think of than a few lines of code that weren't executed.

Comment: The OP won't be the only person to read this, and hardware failures can be caused by more mundane things than missiles.

Comment: @MikeSherrill'CatRecall' Then say that. We don't wan to turn this into something that looks like GITHUb

Answer (score 2):

There is, in fact, a `BEGIN TRY... END TRY...BEGIN CATCH... END CATCH` structure in SQL Server.  I use it quite frequently.

Here's an overview -- the bit about selecting error information is optional, of course -- do what makes sense in your case.

```
BEGIN TRY
        -- do something here.

    /*  Following line can be used to force termination for testing purposes.
        No data changes will be committed.
    */
    --RAISERROR('testing', 99, 1);

    PRINT 'Successful completion; committing transaction.';
    COMMIT TRAN;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    SELECT 
        ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber
        ,ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity
        ,ERROR_STATE() AS ErrorState
        ,ERROR_PROCEDURE() AS ErrorProcedure
        ,ERROR_LINE() AS ErrorLine
        ,ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage;

    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
    RAISERROR(N'Error occurred; rolling back and terminating.',18,1);
END CATCH;
```

Comment: But, unfortunately, there's no `BEGIN FINALLY` and `END FINALLY` (yet) :-(

Comment: Yes, there's no FINALLY clause, but the question also asks about TRY.. CATCH with respect to transactions.  It's a little bit of work, but I can handle most scenarios needing FINALLY given TRY and CATCH.

Comment: You should not use 18 as severity. "Indicates a problem in the Database Engine software":  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164086.aspx  Just reuse the value of ERROR_SEVERITY()

Comment: the ultimate guide to error handling must be http://www.sommarskog.se/error_handling/Part1.html

Answer (score 0):

That last one is going to raise an error every time isn't it.

If you want to trap the rollback error - you'll need to put that in a try..except block also.